# How do I import Vue Material (Webpack UMD) using ESM?

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I have a pug file with the following...

```
#footer
    script(type="module")
          | import Vue from '/vue/vue.esm.browser.js'
          | import { JRGVue } from '/ui/index.js'
          | import VueMaterial from '/material/vue-material.js'
          | (()=>{
          |     const vue = new JRGVue(Vue);
          |     vue.app.use(VueMaterial);
          |     vue.app.$mount('#jg-app');
          | })();
```

I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/material/vue-material.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

When I change it to

```
import * as VueMaterial from '/material/vue-material.js'
```

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: _vue2.default is not a constructor
```

What is the proper way to import the Vue Material library using ESM?

### Update

It does seem to work with Vuetify

```
#footer
    script(type="module")
          | import Vue from '/vue/vue.esm.browser.js'
          | window.Vue = Vue;
    script(type="module")
          | import * as Vuetify from '/vuetify/vuetify.js';
          | import { JRGVue } from '/ui/index.js';
          | Vue.use(Vuetify);
          | const vue = new JRGVue(Vue);
          | vue.app.$mount('#jg-app');
```

### Update

No longer seems to be working with the newest version. It would be really nice to find a UI with native ESM support

Comment: You shouldn't be appending the `.js` extension at the end of the import path, it should be `/material/vue-material`, since it's the `index.js` in the folder/path that exposes all the modules associated with the plugin.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough details and lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . What is /material/vue-material.js ? You know this, others won't. Is it UMD module from vue-material dist folder?

Comment: @Terry I would be careful with that. Pretty sure ESM requires it and I have been noticing it being required in newer versions of node w/ --experimental-modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the import refers to [`vue-material`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-material) library, a correct way to import it is:

```
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material';
```

And bundle the application with it.

It's impossible to import it with native ES  modules (`<script type="module">`).

It's possible to import packages that were built as ES modules (e.g. `vue.esm.browser.js` for `vue`) but `vue-material` doesn't have ES6 entry point.

In case `/material/vue-material.js` refers to `vue-material/dist/vue-material.js`, it is UMD module which cannot be imported by ES module without module interop.

ES module that could be imported is `vue-material/src/index.js` but it cannot be imported directly because the package uses source files that aren't compliant with specs (.vue, .scss) and need to be built.

A way to import `vue-material` UMD module at runtime is to use SystemJS for module interop.

Also, IIFE is an antipattern in module scope.

Comment: So I guess the short answer is that you can't use Material UI with ESM. Is there a material implementation (with vue integration) that does?

Comment: No, you can use ESM with Webpack or use SystemJS for module interop, as I mentioned. You can't use it with *native* ESM. Try Vuetify, it has ESM entry point. Since Vue heavily relies on custom .vue format it's very impractical to use it with native ESM as this will cause the same problem for most third-party libs.